# iOS 7 UINavigationController Push Animation Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a UINavigationController setup in which the Root View Controller has a UITableView that pushes to a detail view. Setup like this the animation is fine, when I add another UINavigationBar below the top bar to act as a backdrop for a UISegmented Control like below the animation develops a strange issue.

This is how I am adding the Navigation Bar:

```
UINavigationBar *selectorBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
[self.view addSubview:selectorBar];
```

And this is what I am achieving with that:
[image]

Here you can see a picture of the issue for the push animation:
[image]

The top bar is just after the back animation begins showing the very noticeable and immediate dark patch that develops on the right side of the bar, and the bottom bar is for contrast showing before the animation starts.

My guess is that for some reason there is no longer a subview behind the bar, so that area has black behind it and that's why it looks like that, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: **when I add another UINavigation Controller below the top bar....** confusion, are you adding navigation Bar or controller ?

Comment: for what you are using two navigation in same class. If you want to use, I suggest you to add a containerView.

Comment: I just updated the question to show why I am using the UINavigationBar